# TabView Inside of NavigationStack has extra inset when ignoring Safe Area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I am using the following code to setup a TabView with a paging style inside of a NavigationStack

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            TabView {
                Color(.green)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
            .tabViewStyle(.page)
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

When this view first appear it looks fine, but as soon as you interact with the view (e.g. swipe up) an extra inset is added at the bottom of the screen. There are interesting issues here as well where if you swipe slowly, the top header will not transform to an inline style but will instead by "frozen" and further swiping on the view will not update it.

Looking into the view hierarchy debugger, it seems like there is some issue with UIKit SwiftUI interop here, as it looks like the TabView with paging style falls back on the UIKit implementation, since I see UIKit views and UIHostingController in the view hierarchy. Based on what I see in the debugger, There is a SwiftUIPagingCollectionView that has the correct height, but there is a UIKitPagingCell subview that has this extra inset causing the issue. Also of note in the view hierarchy debugger, when in the "frozen header" state, I see two headers in the view hierarchy debugger, both seem to be subviews of the UIKitNavigationBar.

Xcode 15
iOS 17

[image: initial view]
[image: view after swipe]
[image: frozen header]
[image]

Comment: Each TabView should have its own NavigationStack, not the other way around.

Comment: @koen that is definitely true if using the bottom bar tab view style. But in this case I want a paging style, where swiping left and right will navigate you between pages. So that navigation stack per page isn't desired here.